# Python list comprehension not working for function parameters

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get a list of all files inside a directory and delete them. I've used the following code and it's working fine.

**Code:**

```
import os

file_list=os.listdir(mypath)
for x in file_list:
    os.remove(mypath+"/"+x)
```

But when I try to do it using the list comprehension way, it's giving a `syntax error`.

```
import os

file_list=os.listdir(mypath)
os.remove(mypath+"/"+x) for x in file_list
```

Can't we call a function with parameter from the list comprehension or is there any other method?

Comment: Aside from the syntax error: why would you use a list comprehension in the first place?  A list comprehension is for when you want to build a list of values.  But here you don't.

Comment: @DSM while using with `"".join(x) for x in file_list`, it worked fine and was more readable. So I thought it'd work the same here. I never expected, it'd build a list and return it. That's why initially I tried without `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also use [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) for getting the path. For 'x' directory and 'y' file, os.file.join('x', 'y') will give you 'x/y'. So, you may use it here like:

```
[os.remove(os.path.join(mypath, x) for x in os.listdir(mypath)]
```

However, use of list comprehension is not required here, as list compression returns a list. In this case you do not want to use the list of `os.remove()`'s objects (Then why to store the objects?). So, it is better to simply use:

```
for x in os.listdir(mypath):
    os.remove(os.path.join(mypath, x)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

file_list=os.listdir(mypath)
[os.remove(mypath+"/"+x) for x in file_list]
```

I guess you missed the `[]`.

Edit:

`Syntax`

```
Following is the syntax for remove() method:

os.remove(path)

Parameters

    path -- This is the path, which is to be removed.

Return Value

This method does not return any value.`
```

Comment: It's working but I didn't understand the difference. When I tried to create a string from the list I can just write `x="".join(x for x in file_list)` but here why we've to put a `[]`? Also it's returning a list with number of elements equals to that of `file_list` and each value set to `None`

Comment: The `[]` is the syntax and the return type is what is being returned by `os.remove(mypath+"/"+x)`.See edit.Remove does not reutrn a value.So you are getting a `None`.

Comment: While this will get the program to compile and run, the accepted has an important point on using list comprehensions just for side effects (i.e. as a regular for loop). The point of a comprehension is to transform an input iterable in some fashion and using it just for the side effect of running `os.remove` is, at best, not idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

file_list=os.listdir(mypath)
[os.remove(mypath + os.sep +x) for x in file_list]
```

or just

```
[os.remove(mypath + os.sep +x) for x in os.listdir(mypath)]
```

or

```
for x in os.listdir(mypath):
    os.remove(mypath + os.sep +x)
```

Comment: i think you could try `[os.remove(mypath + os.sep +x) for x in os.listdir(mypath)]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I've few other works with the `file_list` so doing like this. Else your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, you are trying to delete all files present within some folder. Instead of iterating over all the files of the folder, and delete each file individually, the better way is to use [shutil.rmtree()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html). It will recursively delete all the files for the given path (similar to `rm -r /path/to/folder` in unix).

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree('/path/to/folder')
```